# empty Symfony's profiler?

Tags: php, symfony

I recently discovered that my profiler is not working. Every time I try to open the profiler from `/app_dev.php/_profiler/empty/search/results?ip=&limit=10` I get this empty profiler page:

[image]

With default and customc onfiguration. Here the custom one:

```
framework:
    profiler:
        dsn: 'file:/tmp/symfony-profiler'
```

And here a more precise configuration:

```
framework:
    profiler:
        dsn: "file:%kernel.root_dir%/../var/cache/%kernel.environment%/profiler"
```

No calls are stored in theprofiler. No log keep trace of what happens under the carpet.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony needs the same file permissions to write the profiling data as it would for logs or the cache. Does Symfony write the files if the DSN is left at the default which would write them into `var/cache/dev/profiler` (or app/var with an older version).

It's also possible that the `profiler` service has been overridden, which can be checked with `bin/console debug:container profiler` and other such tools.

Comment: Driver "/home/vagrant/mt-api/app/../var/cache/dev/profiler" is not supported for the profiler.

Comment: Where do the rest of the cache files go then, and what about it you leave the config as normal, to have it use the default?